# Can the Battle Master fighter's Pushing Attack maneuver be used to pull someone past you towards your allies?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, combat-maneuver, forced-movement, battle-master

I have a Battle Master Fighter with the Pushing Attack maneuver. It states that you can push someone 15 feet away from you.

Would that include also behind you as well, since you would be pushing them away from you but also repositioning them behind you to be ambushed by your group? Or does "pushing away" mean at no time can they be pulled towards me and it has to be completely away from me?

Comment: Is your intention to pull it 5 feet and then push it 10 feet?

Comment: Pretty much, unless it has to be all push.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## All Push, no Pull

From my understanding of *Pushing Attack*, you must move the creature you attacked away from you.

The description of the [Battle Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#BattleMaster)'s Pushing Attack [maneuver](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#Maneuvers-214) (PHB, p. 74) says:

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to attempt to drive the target back. You add the superiority die to the attack's damage roll, and if the target is Large or smaller, it must make a Strength saving throw. On a failed save, you push the target up to 15 feet away from you.

The language “you can expend one superiority die to attempt to **drive the target back**” and “you push the target” imply that you do, in fact, push the creature.

The English definition of [*push*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/push) is:

> exert force on (someone or something), typically with one's hand, in order to move them away from oneself or the origin of the force.

The spell [Telekinesis](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/telekinesis) conversely states “you move the creature up to 30 feet”.

**But** you definitely could talk to your DM about allowing a 5-foot pull first. I would recommend explaining how the maneuver would look and offer to quest or train for the ability. Also at no point should you expect your DM to allow the change, but you can ask.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, the more I thought about it the more I realized Pull part was in there, I was just thinking of it in a way where my character used his shield to redirect momentum and shield bash them away. Since my shield has a special "Shield Slam" property to it as a magic item.

Comment: @Someone_Evil I have edited hopefully it is a better answer.

Comment: @DerreckFrost Is the shield a homebrew item? I am not sure what “Shield Slam” does.